# How to get Pytest to recognize my unit testing file

Tags: python, github, pytest, github-actions, cicd

I'm currently trying to manage a GitHub repository for a college class that I'm currently taking, and am trying to get the CI/CD requirements to pass. I've managed to get it through most of the checks, but I can't figure out how to get it to pass tests with pytest. When it reaches this stage, the following output is given:

```
    Run pytest --verbose .
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.0.0, pluggy-1.4.0 -- /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
hypothesis profile 'default' -> database=DirectoryBasedExampleDatabase(PosixPath('/home/runner/work/OOP-ajsaylor/OOP-ajsaylor/.hypothesis/examples'))
rootdir: /home/runner/work/OOP-ajsaylor/OOP-ajsaylor
plugins: hypothesis-6.98.4
collecting ... collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 1.01s =============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 5.
```

I do have a unit testing file for the program I'm looking to test, so my assumption here is that it can't find the testing file.

Because of this, I was wondering if anyone knows what I need to do to get pytest to find my unit testing file. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pytest discovers tests through specific file name, class name, and function name patterns. Make sure your files, classes, and functions are named according to  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery.

Answer (score 2):

Pytest runs all files of the form `test_*.py` or `*_test.py` in the current directory and its subdirectories.

More generally, it follows standard test [discovery rules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the link is removed, it's just a comment. It was already a comment, which this OP copied and pasted as an answer.